# Problem in using ssh from home to university

Tags: ssh

I want to control my lab pc from home using ssh and vnc. But because of firewall of my university, I can't contact my pc from outside. I wonder if there is a way to avoid the firewall and contact my pc.

This is a information of ports. I got it using nap

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-04-11 23:14 KST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00018s latency).
Not shown: 964 closed ports, 30 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
548/tcp  open  afp
631/tcp  open  ipp
5900/tcp open  vnc 
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

If I try connecting my laptop to lap-pc from somewhere in the university. it works fine. But from outside it doesn't work at all.

Can I use port-forwarding to solve this problem? Or is there any other ways to make it?

Comment: short answer #1 : you can't. short answer #2 ask a network admin from your university, if there is an official way to cross firewall he will gave you.

Comment: you need access to a server outside the network. check this [link](http://toic.org/blog/2009/reverse-ssh-port-forwarding/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The network is most likely blocking external requests on port 22.

You do still have some options. Only proceed if you can verify you aren't violating university policy.

1. Use a VPN

Team viewer has a feature that will let you create a private vpn. If you can run a client on you lab pc, this is the simplest option.

http://www.teamviewer.com/en/products/remotecontrol.aspx

2. Ssh over port 443.

This will only work if your computer is not behind a NAT. 
You can ssh over ports other than 22, like port 80 or 443.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/107173/is-it-possible-to-ssh-through-port-80

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried using team viewer and it workded. But since my lab doesn't have any licenses to use the SW, I can't proceed. So I'm going to try to change ssh port now.

Comment: Teamviewer is free for personal use.  Not sure what you mean by 'SW'

Comment: I mean software. And are you meaning that I can use it in my office? Even my university doesn't have its licence?

Comment: Yes, as long as it is for personal use (not for profit, or used by a company to provide remote support), team viewer is free.